# Hide contents of the home directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, nfs, chmod

- I have a lab of computers used by a dozen students.
- Each computer mounts a specific NFS share with a few directories in it, visible to all students.
- Some of the students need a place on the network to save their Project's data, so it becomes available on all of the lab computers.
- For security and privacy reasons, I'd like to hide the list of directories inside the shared workspace, in such a way that if a certain student executes the `ls` command, he/she can see only their own directory, thinking it is the only one there.
- I remember back in the days when I used to work for an ISP using Sparcs running Unix, if a user were to try to list the contents of the /home directory, they'd see only their own (those were the times we used to give them shell accounts to access their mail using the `Pine` command)...

Anyone can tell me what's the appropriate `chmod` command syntax for this?

Answer (score 4):

Say the personal folders are in `/external/nfs/server/share`, so that user `alexp` has their own folder `/external/nfs/server/share/alexp`, owned by them with mode bits 0750 (`rwxr-x---`).

Make the parent folder `/external/nfs/server/share` to be owned by some administrative account and group, with mode bits 0751 (`rwxr-x--x`). In this way, students can *traverse* the directory to get to their personal home on the network, but *cannot list* its contents. See "[Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)" on Unix & Linux SE.